# How to sum across an array, based on matching to row and multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an array where I am trying to sum values across multiple columns. The array looks like this:

| Name | Animal | Animal | Color | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 |  | 3 | 2 |
| John | 1 | 2 | 1 |  |

I am trying to create a table that looks like this:

| Name | Animal | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 | 5 |
| John | 3 | 1 |

Where I am summing across the columns, grouped by the row.

I have tried to do sum and index match, but it is only summing the first occurrence of the column, and not multiple columns. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$E$3*($A$2:$A$3=$A9)*($B$1:$E$1=B$8))`

[image]

Note the use of `$` to lock the row and/or column to not change when dragging the formula.